# Extract unique text from multiple overlapping elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How would I extract the unique `SectionLabels` for each `FormDef`in the following XML:

```
<XML>
<FormDef OID="F_TEST_1" Name="Test Form 1">
    <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_1" />
    <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_4" />
</FormDef>
<FormDef OID="F_TEST_2" Name="Test Form 2">
    <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_2" />
</FormDef>
<FormDef OID="F_TEST_3" Name="Test Form 3">
    <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_2"/>
    <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_3"/>
</FormDef>
<FormDef OID="F_TEST_4" Name="Test Form 4">
    <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_4"/>
</FormDef>

<ItemGroupDef OID="TEST_GROUP_1" Name="Ungrouped">
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_INIT" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_FORMD" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_CONS" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_PGT" />
</ItemGroupDef>
<ItemGroupDef OID="TEST_GROUP_2" Name="MSA1_complyreasG" >
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_NOELIGREAS" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_COMPLYREAS" />
</ItemGroupDef>
<ItemGroupDef OID="TEST_GROUP_3" Name="Ungrouped">
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_INIT" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_FROMD" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_IDV" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_INITBF" />
</ItemGroupDef>
<ItemGroupDef OID="TEST_GROUP_4" Name="MSA2_POARTprecG">
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTPREC" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTNBV" />
    <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_LOARTPREC" />
</ItemGroupDef>

<ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_INIT">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_INIT">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
            <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_FORMD">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_FORMD">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
            <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_MSA1_CONS">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_CONS">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
            <SectionLabel>Section3</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_MSA1_NOELIGREAS">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_NOELIGREAS">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_2">
            <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
            <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_MSA1_COMPLYREAS">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_COMPLYREAS">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_2">
            <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
            <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_INIT">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_INIT">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
            <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_FROMD">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_FROMD">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
            <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_IDV">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_IDV">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
            <SectionLabel>Section3</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTPREC">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTPREC">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
            <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_4">
            <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTNBV">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTNBV">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
            <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_4">
            <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
<ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_MSA2_LOARTPREC">
    <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_LOARTPREC">
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
            <SectionLabel>Section3</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
        <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_4">
            <SectionLabel>Section3</SectionLabel>
        </ItemPresentInForm>
    </ItemDetails>
</ItemDef>
</XML>
```

First I define a key:

```
<xsl:key name="labels" match="ItemDef/ItemDetails/ItemPresentInForm" use="@FormOID" />
```

Then use it in a select like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="sections" 
                select="//*[local-name()='ItemDef']/*[local-name()='ItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ItemPresentInForm']
                           [generate-id() = generate-id(key('labels', @FormOID))]">

                <xsl:value-of select="./SectionLabel" />

            </xsl:variable>
```

But this returns:

Section1
Section1
Section1
Section1

Changing the key to pitch on the `SectionLabel`:

```
<xsl:key name="labels" match="ItemDef/ItemDetails/ItemPresentInForm" use="SectionLabel" />
```

XSLT to transform:

```
                <xsl:variable name="sections" 
                select="//*[local-name()='ItemDef']/*[local-name()='ItemDetails']/*[local-name()='ItemPresentInForm']
                           [generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('labels', SectionLabel))]">

                <xsl:value-of select="./SectionLabel" />

            </xsl:variable>
```

Returns this:

Section1
Section2
Section3
Section4
Section1
Section2
Section3
Section4
Section1
Section2
Section3
Section4
Section1
Section2
Section3
Section4

Which is all the section labels in the document when I am iterating over each FormDef. I am aiming to get an output where only the section labels for the current FormDef are extracted.

The expected output should be:

```
Form OID="F_TEST_1"
Labels: Section1, Section2, Section3 

Form OID="F_TEST_2"
Labels: Section1, Section2 

Form OID="F_TEST_3"
Labels: Section1, Section2, Section3 

Form OID="F_TEST_4"
Labels: Section1, Section2, Section3
```

Thanks

Comment: So, what should be the result? Please, edit the question and provide the exact wanted result. Also, explain more understandably what nodes /values you want selected.

Comment: The output you gave in your answer is what I intended to get. It shows that you understood the question very well.

Comment: I used my *guessing power* to deduce this. Your question would be better defined if you had produced the exact output you wanted. It is a good idea to edit the question and do so, and more importantly, to provide all important information in your future questions.

Comment: Edited to add expected output. It slightly differs from yours but the XSLT you gave is enough. You can of-course edit it if you like. And thanks for the heads up on providing all the information in future - I will sure remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLabelsInForm" match="SectionLabel"
  use="concat(../@FormOID, '+', .)"/>

 <xsl:template match="FormDef">
  Form OID="<xsl:value-of select="@OID"/>"
  Labels: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:variable name="vOID" select="@OID"/>
  <xsl:for-each select=
  "../ItemDef/*/*/SectionLabel
      [generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kLabelsInForm',
                        concat($vOID, '+', .)
                       )
                        [1]
                   )
      ]
  ">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<XML>
    <FormDef OID="F_TEST_1" Name="Test Form 1">
        <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_1" />
        <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_4" />
    </FormDef>
    <FormDef OID="F_TEST_2" Name="Test Form 2">
        <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_2" />
    </FormDef>
    <FormDef OID="F_TEST_3" Name="Test Form 3">
        <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_2"/>
        <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_3"/>
    </FormDef>
    <FormDef OID="F_TEST_4" Name="Test Form 4">
        <ItemGroupRef ItemGroupOID="TEST_GROUP_4"/>
    </FormDef>
    <ItemGroupDef OID="TEST_GROUP_1" Name="Ungrouped">
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_INIT" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_FORMD" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_CONS" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_PGT" />
    </ItemGroupDef>
    <ItemGroupDef OID="TEST_GROUP_2" Name="MSA1_complyreasG" >
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_NOELIGREAS" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_COMPLYREAS" />
    </ItemGroupDef>
    <ItemGroupDef OID="TEST_GROUP_3" Name="Ungrouped">
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_INIT" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_FROMD" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_IDV" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_INITBF" />
    </ItemGroupDef>
    <ItemGroupDef OID="TEST_GROUP_4" Name="MSA2_POARTprecG">
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTPREC" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTNBV" />
        <ItemRef ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_LOARTPREC" />
    </ItemGroupDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_INIT">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_INIT">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
                <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_FORMD">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_FORMD">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
                <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_MSA1_CONS">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_CONS">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
                <SectionLabel>Section3</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_MSA1_NOELIGREAS">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_NOELIGREAS">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_2">
                <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
                <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA1_MSA1_COMPLYREAS">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA1_MSA1_COMPLYREAS">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_2">
                <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
                <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_INIT">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_INIT">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
                <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_FROMD">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_FROMD">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
                <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_IDV">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_IDV">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_3">
                <SectionLabel>Section3</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTPREC">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTPREC">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
                <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_4">
                <SectionLabel>Section1</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTNBV">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_POARTNBV">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
                <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_4">
                <SectionLabel>Section2</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
    <ItemDef OID="I_MSA2_MSA2_LOARTPREC">
        <ItemDetails ItemOID="I_MSA2_MSA2_LOARTPREC">
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_1">
                <SectionLabel>Section3</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
            <ItemPresentInForm FormOID="F_TEST_4">
                <SectionLabel>Section3</SectionLabel>
            </ItemPresentInForm>
        </ItemDetails>
    </ItemDef>
</XML>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (the unique `SectionLabel` values for each form):

```
  Form OID="F_TEST_1"
  Labels: Section1 Section2 Section3 

  Form OID="F_TEST_2"
  Labels: Section1 Section2 

  Form OID="F_TEST_3"
  Labels: Section1 Section2 Section3 

  Form OID="F_TEST_4"
  Labels: Section1 Section2 Section3
```

**Explanation**:

- Muenchian grouping method where the elements to be grouped are indexed using a composite key.
- Each unique section value in a form is identified by the concatenation of the `SectionLabel` string value and the string value of the `FormOID` attribute of its parent.
- In this way the same `SectionLabel` value in different forms produces different keys and isn't counted just once.

**Here are some good resources on Muenchian grouping**:

- **[Jeni Tennison's grouping page](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.
- [**`Dave Pawson's XSLT FAQ's grouping page`**](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html).

Comment: You my dear friend are my hero. This works like a charm. Just a request, could you in "lay-man's terms" explain how you are generating the sections using the key?

Comment: @Kata: You are welcome. Yes, I updated the answer with a more detailed explanation.